# VLC Not Working in Kubuntu 16.04.1

Tags: command-line, kubuntu, kde, samba, vlc

VLC Media Player is not working in Kubuntu 16.04.1. When I open a file in it, it flashes the play/pause button really fast for about 5 seconds and then the file seems to be closed. The output of VLC when opened in terminal is:

```
VLC media player 2.2.2 Weatherwax (revision 2.2.2-0-g6259d80)
[0000000002122148] core libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
KSambaShare: Could not find smb.conf!
org.kde.kurifilter-shorturi: "smb://192.168.1.2/Files"
org.kde.kurifilter-shorturi: path = ""  isLocalFullPath= false  exists= false  url= QUrl("smb://192.168.1.2/Files")
org.kde.kurifilter-ikws: "smb://192.168.1.2/Files" : QUrl("smb://192.168.1.2/Files") , type = 0
libdvdnav: Using dvdnav version 5.0.3
libdvdread: Encrypted DVD support unavailable.
************************************************
**                                            **
**  No css library available. See             **
**  /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/README.css     **
**  for more information.                     **
**                                            **
************************************************
libdvdread: Couldn't find device name.
libdvdread:DVDOpenFilePath:findDVDFile /VIDEO_TS/VIDEO_TS.IFO failed
libdvdread:DVDOpenFilePath:findDVDFile /VIDEO_TS/VIDEO_TS.BUP failed
libdvdread: Can't open file VIDEO_TS.IFO.
libdvdnav: vm: failed to read VIDEO_TS.IFO
[00000000021f0d68] core playlist: stopping playback
[00007efe9c016438] idummy demux: command `nop'
[00007efe9c012c38] idummy demux: command `nop'
[00007efe9c000ec8] idummy demux: command `nop'
[00007efe9c00dcf8] idummy demux: command `nop'
[00007efe9c00dcf8] idummy demux: command `nop'
[00007efe9c00dcf8] idummy demux: command `nop'
[00007efe9c00dcf8] idummy demux: command `nop'
[00007efe9c00dcf8] idummy demux: command `nop'
[00007efe9c012b18] idummy demux: command `nop'
[00007efe9c012b18] idummy demux: command `nop'
[00007efe9c012b18] idummy demux: command `nop'
[00007efe9c013698] idummy demux: command `nop'
[00007efe9c00ca28] idummy demux: command `nop'
[00007efe9c00ca28] idummy demux: command `nop'
[00007efe940012c8] idummy demux: command `nop'
[00007efe9c008848] idummy demux: command `nop'
[00007efe94000fc8] idummy demux: command `nop'
[00007efe9c014868] idummy demux: command `nop'
[00007efe9400b248] idummy demux: command `nop'
[00007efe9c00cbf8] idummy demux: command `nop'
[00007efe94005698] idummy demux: command `nop'
[00007efe9c015638] idummy demux: command `nop'
org.kde.knotifications: env says KDE is running but SNI unavailable -- check KDE_FULL_SESSION and XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
[00007efe9c015638] idummy demux: command `nop'
[00007efe94004868] idummy demux: command `nop'
[00007efe9c009a18] idummy demux: command `nop'
[00007efe94008398] idummy demux: command `nop'
[00007efe9c00c868] idummy demux: command `nop'
[00007efe9400b068] idummy demux: command `nop'
[00007efe94000af8] idummy demux: command `nop'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try running this single command: `sudo apt-get install libdvd-pkg && sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg` and then try again...

Comment: @andrew.46 Thanks! That fixed it! Although, when I turned on the PC the day after the problems were happening, it just started working. It wouldn't play off my network share, though. But now it does! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need the libdvdcss package which on Xenial can be installed with the following two commands:

```
sudo apt-get install libdvd-pkg
sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg
```

This should be enough to kick start your copy of vlc...